# Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler:javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:

Tags: javascript, groovy, jmeter, password-encryption, jsr223

I have an encrypt.js script that is used to encrypt and decrypt the password entered by user. It is embedded in the application webpage.

I try to load the same script in jmeter using this code

```
load ('/apache-jmeter-5.6.3/scripts/encrypt.js');
```

upon running it, I got this error.

2024-02-27 09:55:47,729 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.load() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [/apache-jmeter-5.6.3/scripts/encrypt.js]

In the language, I used groovy since there is no javascript in the dropdown list. How can I successfully import the javascript in jmeter?

[jmeter jsr223 sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjtWe.jpg)

Trying to load and encryption js provided by the dev to successfully login into the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to use [Global.load()](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mozilla/rhino/1.7.14/org/mozilla/javascript/tools/shell/Global.html#load-org.mozilla.javascript.Context-org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable-java.lang.Object:A-org.mozilla.javascript.Function-) function from [Mozilla Rhino](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino) to load an external [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) file - you won't be able to do this using Groovy language. You will need to switch to `javascript`

For example if your "encrypt.js" file has the following function:

```
function myFunction(name) {
  return 'Hello, ' + name + '!'
}
```

you can load it and call it in JMeter as follows:

[image]

However be aware that using JavaScript is:

1. Not recommended in general because Nashorn engine has been removed from JDK15 and you will have troubles with running your test on newer Java versions
2. Is kind of a performance anti-pattern, [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) for scripting especially for cryptographic operations so I would rather suggest implementing your encryption logic in Groovy rather than trying to call JavaScript from Java. See [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) and [Encryption and decryption with Groovy](https://groovy.apache.org/blog/encryption-and-decryption-with-groovy) for more details.

Comment: tried using the code from here https://groovy.apache.org/blog/encryption-and-decryption-with-groovy but getting a lot of errors.

Comment: here are the errors i got 2024-02-27 16:30:35,572 INFO o.a.j.m.J.JSR223 Pre Password Masking - Groovy: This is the user's password: a2 Password_1
2024-02-27 16:30:35,572 INFO o.a.j.m.J.JSR223 Pre Password Masking - Groovy: This is the user's masked password: a2 **********
2024-02-27 16:30:35,572 INFO o.a.j.m.J.JSR223 Pre Password Masking - Groovy: This is the user's encryption key: a3 60EDW2WQ47CK8VB2KDL5TF7Q7EEYNO95
2024-02-27 16:30:35,588 ERROR o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 Pre Password Encryption
javax.script.ScriptException:

Comment: javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script18.groovy: 31: unable to resolve class Cipher
 @ line 31, column 33.
   def randomParameterSpec(Closure<Cipher> factory) {
Script18.groovy: 34: unable to resolve class IvParameterSpec
 @ line 34, column 5.
       new IvParameterSpec(block)
Script18.groovy: 37: unable to resolve class Key
 @ line 37, column 27.
   def encrypt(byte[] bytes, Key key, IvParameterSpec spec, Closure<Cipher> factory)

Comment: You need to add necessary [import statements](https://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_imports) like `import javax.crypto.Cipher`, `import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec`, etc. to the beginning of your script. Also check out [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) article to learn more about JMeter-specific objects you can use in your scripts for accessing i.e. JMeter Variables or writing entries to [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging).

Comment: understand.. how will I know which import statements or packages i need to add to the code? I'm really new to this language..

Comment: Getting this error now 2024-02-29 09:00:02,105 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler - Password Encryption, message: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: ENCRYPT_MODE for class: Script1
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: ENCRYPT_MODE for class: Script1. I have included the following classes import javax.crypto.Cipher
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator
import java.security.Key
import java.security.SecureRandom